# @Autowired and TransactionProxyFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a repository class that is created in XML like so:

```
<bean id="stuffRepositoryTarget" class="my.stuff.RepositoryImpl">
 <!-- some params -->
</bean>

<bean id="stuffRepository" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" primary="true">
  <property name="target" ref="stuffRepositoryTarget" />
  <property name="transactionAttributes">
     <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And then I have a class that uses the repository like this:

```
@Autowired Repository repository;
```

It appears that the @Autowired annotation is referring to my Impl object and not my transaction interceptor.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the bean created by the `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` does not implement `Repository`.

Just checking, but `Repository` *is* an interface, right?

Another thing to try is to mark `stuffRepositoryTarget` with `autowire-candidate="false"`, which will prevent it from being accidentally auto-wired.

Comment: autowire-candidate="false" is a cool trick that I was not aware of.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It's only fair, you taught me an obscure fact about autowiring the other day :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be confusion over which bean to inject... Add a qualifier to your bean reference with which you can specify the exact bean id that you wish to have injected.

Something like:

```
@Qualifier("stuffRepository")
@Autowired Repository repository;
```